# Synchronous logging with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am simply to create some synchronous logging with Node.js.

I believe console.log is synchronous, but I am looking to use process.stdout, a writable stream.

This is what I have so far:

```
var messages = [];
var okToWrite = true;

process.stdout.on('finish', function () {

    okToWrite = true;
    if (messages.length > 0) {
        runnerLog(messages.pop());
    }

});

module.exports = function runnerLog(data) {

    if (okToWrite) {
        okToWrite = false;
        process.stdout.write(data);
        process.stdout.end();
    }
    else {
        messages.push(data);
    }

};
```

the problem is that the finish event is never fired, and I also tried listening for the drain event, but that didn't seem to be fired either. Calling `process.stdout.end()` just seemed to cause problems. Should I be calling `process.stdout.flush()?`

I am not sure if I need synchronous logging, but either way this code will not lock up the event loop as I am using async I/O and not waiting for anything, etc. It's all evented.

From the docs for Node.js process, it looks like calling end() will throw and finish never gets called:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout

so perhaps I should use a different writable stream other than process.stdout and pipe it to process.stdout? No idea.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but isn't process.stdout.on('finish') called when the node process is finished? Why would you want to log only at the end? If something goes wrong, it's good to have immediatelly the log that was sent so far. Or am I missing something?

Comment: no I think process.stdout finish event is called when the stream is flushed, I also read that the event was called drain so I am confused. This is a long running process and I want this work independent of the event loop shutting down.

Comment: according to the docs, `finish` is triggered when `close` has been called **after** all data has been `flushed` - so, @Gavriel is correct

Comment: hmmm but the docs say that the finish event is never triggered for process.stdout, see the link at the bottom of the post

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to store all messages and display them only at the end? If so, listen to `process.on('exit')` and write `messages` to stdout at this point only. If you don't care for realtime logging, it may be better to stream the messages to a file, that would be async and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that process.stdout.write, at least when directed at a terminal/console is already synchronous. There doesn't appear to be a need to add anything. Furthermore it doesn't appear that the process.stdout stream fires the events needed to make my original design for sync logging possible, as outlined in my question.

Comment: This *can* be true, but not always. See https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/process.html#a-note-on-process-io